# Why is ColdFusion STARTUP, PARSING, COMPILING, LOADING, & SHUTDOWN load time so slow?

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion 11 web site which is running very slowly and I can't find out why. The entire site runs very slowly and it does not seem to be code related, but something with the server settings. Here is a snapshot of the template execution times on one of the quicker pages. You can see that all of the templates execute without an issue, but then the STARTUP, PARSING, COMPILING, LOADING & SHUTDOWN section takes up a chunk of time. This is even more pronounced on more involved templates. Any suggestions as to what I can do to speed this up?

```
Total Time  Avg Time    Count   Template 

0 ms    0 ms    1   CFC[ D:/.../Application.cfc | onRequestEnd(/admin/login.cfm) ] from D:/.../Application.cfc 
0 ms    0 ms    1   CFC[ D:/.../Application.cfc | onRequestStart(/admin/login.cfm) ] from D:/.../Application.cfc 
0 ms    0 ms    1   D:/.../admin/assets/includes/footer.cfm 
0 ms    0 ms    1   D:/.../admin/assets/includes/header.cfm 
0 ms    0 ms    1   D:/.../admin/assets/includes/sidebar.cfm 
0 ms    0 ms    1   top level D:\...\admin\login.cfm 
1328 ms     STARTUP, PARSING, COMPILING, LOADING, & SHUTDOWN 
1328 ms     TOTAL EXECUTION TIME
```

Comment: What are you parsing?  That could lend some clues? I'm talking about sidebar.cfm, login.cfm and Application.cfc

Comment: I'm really not sure how to answer this question without posting the code for all of the templates. The Application.cfc does normal application things - sets some variables, includes headers and footers, handles errors and things like that. The other templates just display the header, footer and sidebar. I wouldn't describe any of it as "parsing".

Comment: or compiling or loading, whatever. If you want some help best to post what CF is gagging on, right? :D

Comment: Is that the entire output? All of those entries took `0 ms` so the slowness appears to be happening somewhere else. I would start breaking this up to debug. Start with a simple ColdFusion template that sets a variable and outputs it (no header, no footer, no sidebar). How long does that take? Then start adding the other templates one by one until you see the slowness.

Comment: Install a tool such as Fusion Reactor and watch stack traces and memory spaces while your code runs. I've seen things like full hard drives or bad network latency cause behaviors like this but there's no telling without looking under the hood.

Comment: Do you have other sites that take less time for that set of actions?

Comment: I have other sites. One of them does the same thing as this site and the other is much quicker. However, the one that is much quicker is basically just an HTML site with an Application.cfc and some includes for headers and footers. Both of the sites that do the more intensive CF type work have this problem with the slowdown at the "startup, parsing, compiling, loading, & shutdown" phase.

Comment: Looks like a similar issue, mentioned in the https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3758172

Comment: It looks like Adobe is having problems. I'm trying to link to that site and I'm getting errors.

Comment: Ok, I was able to load the bug, finally. I don't think the problems are really related as the bug is a problem that only exists on the first load and this happens on every load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem we were having here was the result of our client data management being bogged down. It was set to store data for all client variables up to 90 days and was eating up system resources. Every time someone hit a page on our server it had to churn through so much client data it was causing a big system slowdown. This is why the time is reflected in the section that it is. It wasn't any particular template, but rather in the startup that the slowdown occurred.

The solution was to scale back client data storage. We now only store data for up to 24 hours. After that it gets purged. Things are running much better now.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the overhead of having debugging switched on. I would not worry about it. What are the metrics like if you have debugging switched off? One can draw no valid performance conclusions whilst debugging is on.